# Blazor Setting DateTime value in one field updates DateTime value in another field

Tags: datetime, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I have an edit form of two DateTime fields.. which are created based of a model. My goal is so that if you change the DateTime of the `DateStarted` field..it will update the value of `DateStartedCopy` field and keep on updating dynamically depending on what is chosen in the `DateStarted` field.. Yet I still want the user to have the capability to still override that option and choose to select their own DateTime if need be..

```
        <p>
            <label for="datestarted">1.Date Started<span style="color: red">*</span> </label><br />
            <InputDate class="inputFieldSize" id="datestarted" @bind-Value="_supervisorData.DateStarted" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="datestartedcopy">2.Date Started Copy<span style="color: red">*</span> </label> <br />
  
            <InputDate class="inputFieldSize" id="datestartedcopy" @bind-Value="_supervisorData.DateStartedCopy" />

        </p>
```

Then in my `@code`

```
SupervisorData _supervisorData = new SupervisorData() {Processed = false};

 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _supervisorData = new SupervisorData() {DateStarted = DateTime.Today, DateStartedCopy= DateTime.Now};

    }
```

Then my actual model `Supervisor Data`

```
[Required]
public DateTime DateStarted { get; set; }
    
[Required]
public DateTime DateStartedCopy{ get; set; }
```

I thought an approach would be to possibly change my getter;setter methods..to set the value of DateStartedCopy = DateStarted, but i believe my option is to perhaps do an `onchange` event in the form? What sort of approach should I be taking here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <input type="date" class="inputFieldSize" id="datestarted" 
           @bind-value="_supervisorData.DateStarted" 
           @bind-value:event="oninput" 
           @onchange="()=> { this._supervisorData.DateStartedCopy = this._supervisorData.DateStarted; }" />
```

This works, but it useses the input type="date" instead of the InputDate, so you can define @bind-value:event="oninput".

When I try to only add @onchange, additionally to the @bind-value inside the InputDate, the onchange doesn't get called.
When I try to use @oninput inside the InputDate, the @oninput gets called before the change of _supervisorData.DateStarted, so you have the wrong value.

Adding "this._supervisorData.DateStartedCopy = this._supervisorData.DateStarted;" to the setter like you mentioned works, too.

Comment: Thank you.. your first method of using input type="date" does partially work..but the thing is, now when i change the date in `DateStartedCopy` it also updates the `DateStarted` whereas how i wanted it is.. `DateStarted` updates `DateStartedCopy` but `DateStartedCopy` can still override with its own date without affecting the original

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If I run the code and change DateStartedCopy, then DateStarted doesn't get changed. And that's how you want it to work, isn't it? There is no code that could change DateStarted when DateStartedCopy is changed.

Comment: That's strange.. I wonder why my `DateStarted` is getting changed when i change `DateStartedCopy`

Comment: How does your `DateStarted` code look like? Is that also an input type="date" or similar to my original

Comment: The one I posted was the Code for the DateStarted Input. The DateStartedCopy Input is the same you used in your original code

Comment: A slap in the face for me.. i was replacing the wrong InputDate field...thank you it works perfectly.